# Calling SP with sys_refcursor as out parameter inside another procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sys-refcursor

I have an SP

```
create or replace PROCEDURE         ALTERNATE_NAME_LOOKUP
 ( P_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
  P_TYPE IN VARCHAR2, retCursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
 )
```

I didn't paste the rest of its body; The above procedure works fine on its own (with the body of course)

Now I want to call it from another stored procedure, and I want to traverse over the refcursor.

What I am doing is declaring `an_last_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;` and calling ALTERNATE_NAME_LOOKUP procedure as `ALTERNATE_NAME_LOOKUP(p_req.LASTNAMEEXP,c_LAST, an_last_cur);` It compiles.
but when I add following block -

```
 ALTERNATE_NAME_LOOKUP('Roman Reigns','LAST',an_last_cur);
      For alt in an_last_cur
      Loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ok');
      end loop;
```

It gives compilation error -

```
 PLS-00221: 'AN_LAST_CUR' is not a procedure or is undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I am calling  the sp as `ALTERNATE_NAME_LOOKUP('Roman Reigns','LAST',:an_last_cur);` it gives `PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'AN_LAST_CUR'`

Comment: Refcursors are just not the solution you should look in this case. Use Collections and then pass it as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try this one. Hope this helps. I dont have workspace with me so pardon
>   syntax erro r if any.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_ref_prc
  ( p_ref_out  OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN p_ref_out FOR
  SELECT LEVEL  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_ref2
AS
refc sys_refcursor;
num_ntt NUMBER_NTT;
BEGIN
test_ref_prc(refc);
FETCH refc BULK COLLECT INTO num_ntt;
FOR I IN num_ntt.FIRST..num_ntt.LAST LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(num_ntt(i));
END LOOP;
END;

exec test_ref2;
```

Comment: I am trying to open sys_refcursor (output of ALTERNATE_NAME_LOOKUP) inside current procedure

Comment: Check now. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

```
create or replace procedure alternate_name_lookup
 ( p_name in varchar2, p_type in varchar2, retcursor out sys_refcursor ) 
as
begin
  open retcursor for select * from user_objects ;     
end;

set serveroutput on
declare
  an_last_cur sys_refcursor;
  type my_objects is table of user_objects%rowtype;
  objects my_objects;
begin
  alternate_name_lookup('Roman Reigns','LAST',an_last_cur);

  fetch an_last_cur bulk collect into objects;
  dbms_output.put_line(objects.count);

  for indx in 1 .. objects.count 
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(objects(indx).object_name);
  end loop;  

  close an_last_cur;
end;
```